# Jquery i cant get attribute ( undefined )

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

Hey guys thats my question

> i cant get an attribute with $sender.attr('data-id') or $sender.data('id')

When i use the code like this "alert($sender.attr('data-id'));" the result is undefined so i am here

Here is my JS function

```
function sol(sender) {
var btn = $(sender);
var sira = btn.attr("data-id");//here is my problem
```

}

And my html code is

```
    <input class="btn btn-default left" type="button" value="Sol" onclick="sol()"
data-id="%Response.Write(HiddenField2.Value.Split('/')[i].Split('#')[1]); %>"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onclick` event, you are supposed to send a value for the `sender`. So change it to:

```
onclick="sol(this);"
```

And this would send the `<input />` to the function and it should work fine.